# AJAX call PHPExcel output file is empty

Tags: php, ajax

I start with this code:

index.html:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "htmltable_to_excel/savexls.php",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({'name': 'test'}),
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    async: false,
    success: function(result)
    {
        alert(result);
        //window.open("htmltable_to_excel/savexls.php",'_blank');
    }
});
```

savexls.php:

```
$val = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($val, true);
echo $json['name'];
```

It is return 'test'. AJAX call seems good.

I have code for created xlsx via PHPExcel:

savexls.php:

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

$val = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($val, true);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $json['name']);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
// header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But when I open the created xlsx file cell is empty. I forgetting something here? What could be the problem? Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in error.log? If not then try to debug it step by step using var_dump and die;

Comment: Lose the `JSON.stringify` and send the object as is: `data: {'name': 'test'},`. jQuery will handle the rest. Then in your PHP, use `$_POST['name']` instead of `php://input` to get the value. Btw, why do you have `async: false` on that request?

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the Excel file? You're currently returning the actual source of the file to your ajax callback. You also define that the response should be treated as `dataType: 'text'`, while you're setting a completely different content type in the response. You simply can't do a "download" in a ajax request like that.

Comment: In the apache error log I could not find so much useful logs:

Comment: [:error] [pid 2460:tid 1608] [client ::1:50629] , referer: http://localhost:8089/PHPExcelProject/
And
PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://localhost:8089/PHPExcelProject/

Comment: -But when I'm using the following ajax request:
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "htmltable_to_excel/savexls.php", data: {'name': 'test'}, ... and I changed the $val variable to be equal with $_POST and use: **error_log(var_dump($val)); die();** in savexls.php, theb the browser result in a new tab will be: **array (size=0) empty** but in the Developer mode (Chrome) Network->Response tab it show the following:<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>'name' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'test'</font> <i>(length=4)</i></pre>